# How to print multiple html files?

Tags: windows, printing, batch-file

How can I print multiple html files located on web, and not on a local drive?

Something like:

- http://www.domain.com/file.html?ID=1
- http://www.domain.com/file.html?ID=2
- http://www.domain.com/file.html?ID=3
- http://www.domain.com/file.html?ID=4
- ...
- http://www.domain.com/file.html?ID=*n*

Can I create a batch file? Or is there a better approach to print about 500 html documents, each only different by `?ID=`.

Comment: I think this question should be migrated to superuser

Comment: Which OS? Please provide any relevant details.

Comment: Windows 7, or Windows XP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with Windows PowerShell (available natively on Windows 7, must be downloaded for Windows XP/Vista)

The quick and dirty script looks like this (you can paste it to a PowerShell window or save as a .ps1 file):

```
$ie = new-object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible = $false
$url = "http://www.domain.com/file.html?ID="
For ($id=1; $id -le 500; $id++) {
  $ie.Navigate($url+$id.ToString())
  while ($ie.busy) {start-sleep -milliseconds 500}
  $ie.ExecWB(6,2)
}
```

This should work if your `ID`s really are sequential (from 1 to 500).

**What it does:**

- Create an Internet Explorer instance (not visible)
- Set the desired URL (minus the ID number at the end)
- Loop throught all IDs from 1 to 500 and print them to your default printer (the `$ie.ExecWB(6,2)` line)

Comment: Looks interesting. How to run a ps1 file? I am using command "powershell -noexit test.ps1", but I get an error that ps1 file is not valid

Comment: @John - try using the full path to the script file: `powershell.exe -noexit &'c:\Documents and Settings\username\My Documents\test.ps1'`. See [this page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176949.aspx#EBAA) for more information

Comment: Actually I have visited that particular page, but I end up with this error. The term 'c:\print.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, sc
ript file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path wa
s included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:13
+ c:\print.ps1 <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (c:\print.ps1:String) [], Comman
   dNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0>

Comment: Furthermore I get the error, unable to access to the registry key when i execute Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned.

Comment: Used [page](http://bartvdw.wordpress.com/2008/04/22/powershell-executionpolicy/) to set Execution Policy.