# How can I get Acrobat to make a pdf that includes posts from a private Google+ community I host?

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I ask this question because Google+ communities are being discontinued and I want to create an archive of a private Google+ community I host. I have used Takeout to get a list of all the URLs in the private Google+ community, but Acrobat doesn't know how to view those webpages when I use the Create File from Web Page option on Acrobat. (That option works just fine for a public Google+ community.) Is there a workaround?  In other words, how can I get Create File from Web Page option on Acrobat to view the webpages exported by Takeout?

Answer (score 0):

Acrobat is not the tool for downloading Google+ communities data.

In [takeout.google.com](http://takeout.google.com/),
after selecting the Google+ data you want to keep, you should choose
the format (HTML?), then select the folder and the format.
The recommended format is `.zip`.

After the download, you may unzip the zip archive to extract all the files,
then you may view them (in the browser for HTML).
You may then print them on a PDF virtual printer.

If you wish to batch convert all the files to PDF, set the default printer
to the Adobe (or Microsoft) virtual PDF printer and use the script
from the post
[How to print multiple html files?](https://superuser.com/questions/400650/how-to-print-multiple-html-files).

Comment: Thanks for taking time to reply.  I have edited my question to make clearer that my question is about using the Create File from Web Page option on Acrobat.  That option allows one to capture more than the first level of URLs, which I'd like to have happen.

Comment: An example would help.

Comment: Below is a made-up example.  (A real example won't help because you will not be able to open any of the urls from the posts on a private google+ community.) List of URLs produced by takeout: https://plus.google.com/+petertaylorip/posts/9LiGWxQKJZv
https://plus.google.com/+petertaylorip/posts/at4z5597yNd
https://plus.google.com/+petertaylorip/posts/cBeoB9zc6rM
https://plus.google.com/+petertaylorip/posts/WPFCW2GgxiK

Comment: Here is a screenshot from Acrobat: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ERLbvkKu_BCgLUJMFA9e-oDAMTAtAJ0D/view?usp=sharing . And

Comment: I think I understand - you have a list of URLs that you are trying to convert to PDF directly from the Web. What's preventive you from taking my above approach to download all the files to your computer, where they will be safe? But I think your biggest worry are really the inner URL links in the documents that point to other documents or to the Web. I need to think about it, about a solution that will create a viable website.

Comment: To download all the URLs and the URLs inside the URLs means that I would be giving up on using the Create File from Web Page option on Acrobat.  My question is how to get Acrobat to view the webpages from Takeout when I use the Create File from Web Page option on Acrobat.

Comment: My Acrobat does not have this option, but I repeat my warning that your procedure will not create a viable copy of the community, since inter-community URLs will no longer work. You need a program that will download for you the whole community and correct the links. [HTTrack](https://www.httrack.com/) is often used for that, but you could also try another [HTTrack alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/httrack/).